# Replace IIf with SWITCH in WHERE clause

Tags: ms-access, switch-statement, ms-access-2003

I have the following query in MS-Access 2003 and it works OK:

```sql
SELECT tblDiscounts.DiscountID, tblDiscounts.DiscountPercent, tblDiscounts.DiscountName, tblDiscounts.DiscountDescription
FROM tblDiscounts, qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested
WHERE (tblDiscounts.DiscountID) = IIf ([qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=1,1,IIf([qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=2,2,IIf([qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=3,3,4)));
```

I wish to replace the IIf function with the Switch function but whatever I tried didn't work. My best approach is the following:

```sql
SELECT tblDiscounts.DiscountID, tblDiscounts.DiscountPercent, tblDiscounts.DiscountName, tblDiscounts.DiscountDescription
FROM tblDiscounts, qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested
WHERE (((tblDiscounts.DiscountID)=SWITCH ([qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=1,1, [qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=2,2, [qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]=3,3, [qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]>3,4)));
```

but I get a message

> Type mismatch in expression

Please advise!

Comment: MS Access doesn't have a Switch function. It does have a Select Case function but I'm not aware that you can use it in SQL. If you want to use Switch you need to use SQL Server with ADO or a Pass Through Query.

Comment: Oops, I should pay better attention. Sorry about the incorrect information.

Answer (score 2):

One difference I can see is that if `[qryPropertyPeriodRate_Count_Nested].[CountOfWeeks]<1` the nested `IIf`s will return `4` while the `Switch` statement will return `Null`. Check your underlying data to see if that could happen; a `Null` value might very well mess up the WHERE clause.

Comment: As Gord says, you need to handle the case where none of your conditions matched, like so: `switch(c1 = v1, 1, c2 = v2, 2, ..., true, 4)`

Comment: Thank you Gord and Yawar. The user may not select 0 weeks. My problem is the message I get "Type mismatch in expression" which is not happening using the Iif instead of Switch.